# How to restart the screen with action listener?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I was looking in to my Java project when I realized I have yet to make my title screen. But one problem came to mind: How do I make it in where when they press on the new file button it will clear everything on the screen and put the new stuff in?

In simpler words, how to make a action listener so when they click the button the screen will clear and put a new screen on?

```
package Main_Config;

    import java.awt.*;

    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.border.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;

    public class SET_UP extends JFrame {

            private JPanel contentPane;
            private JTextField textField;
            private JLabel consol;
            public static Dimension size = new Dimension(800, 700);


            /**
             * Launch the application.
             */
            public static void main(String[] args) {

            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                            try {

                                    SET_UP frame = new SET_UP();
                                    frame.setVisible(true);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                    }
            });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public SET_UP() {

            setResizable(false);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setBounds(370, 70, 0, 0);
            contentPane = new JPanel();
            contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
            setContentPane(contentPane);
            contentPane.setLayout(null);
            setSize(size);
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);

            textField = new JTextField();
            textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                            String input = textField.getText(); 
                                consol.setText(input);

                    }
            });
            textField.setBounds(10, 452, 243, 20);
            contentPane.add(textField);
            textField.setColumns(10);

            JButton enter = new JButton("Enter");
            enter.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                }
            });

                enter.setBounds(253, 452, 89, 20);
            contentPane.add(enter);

            JLabel consol = new JLabel("");
            consol.setBounds(0, 483, 335, 189);
            contentPane.add(consol);

            JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
            btnNewButton.setBounds(352, 451, 200, 23);
            contentPane.add(btnNewButton);

            JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("New button");
            btnNewButton_1.setBounds(584, 451, 200, 23);
            contentPane.add(btnNewButton_1);

            JButton btnNewButton_2 = new JButton("New button");
            btnNewButton_2.setBounds(0, 0, 89, 23);
            contentPane.add(btnNewButton_2);
    }
}
```

Comment: `"I have no code to share but you may share your code."` -- Seriously? How about `"No"`. If you're unwilling to put in the effort to share your code, then we're better off just closing this question. So voted. If you want a decent answer, please be prepared to show the fruits of your efforts, and also put effort into asking a decent question.

Comment: I would share my code but um well her...I will edit to change your mind but let me warn you that its not that easy to read....

Answer (score 0):

To clear the screen, I do this:

```
Button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                frame.setVisible(false);
                frame.remove(panelTwo);
                frame.remove(panelThree);
                frame.add(panelFour);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
```